# How do i convert a P2 pgm to a P5 pgm using Opencv?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

i'm using a chan-vese segmentation code that only works with P5 pgm files, but i need to use it with P2 pgm files as well.
i am using OpenCV to try to convert it from P2 to P5, the problem i'm having is that i get an error when i try to save the image to binary format (used in P5). here the code:

```
Mat imag(imread("path_to_file.pgm", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE));

vector<int> param;
param.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PXM_BINARY);
param.push_back(1);

try
    {
        imwrite("P5_file.pgm", imag, param);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &erro)
    {
        cout << &erro;
    }
```

When debugging in Visual Studio, when the function imwrite is used i get an error in xutility internal header, i have no idea where this is from, but it shows me that its an access violation. _Pnext.

if i try to change the flag for reading the image, then i get:

Error: Bad argument (Portable bitmap(.pgm) expects gray image)

what is wrong here?

Comment: Hard to tell. What version of OpenCV, what platform, etc. Could you provide a sample input file that we can try to reproduce this with? (BTW, [mcve] means that the code is complete -- i.e. there is a `main()`, all the necessary includes, and anything else needed to compile the code and reproduce the problem)

Comment: i solved it by saving the image to a .tiff first, then loading it and saving it in P5